# Java: Program continues to terminate with no logical operator errors

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, console-application, logical-operators

Java files: https://github.com/whimsicalusername/CIT230Final

My Java final is a "game" designed by my professor.  Pieces can only move one space (forward - col to col) towards each other unless you're in a spot in the grid where your square is touching any other square, including diagonal.  My issue seems to be here and I've tried to rewrite it numerous ways but I'm stuck:

```
package cit230.pkgfinal;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Game {

    private static Boolean gameRunning;
    private static Piece[][] gB = new Piece[8][8];
    private static Stack<String> lostPieces = new Stack<>();
    char a = 'A';
    private static String move;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Source rows and columns
    private static int sRow, sCol;
    // Destination rows and columns
    private static int dRow, dCol;

    // Starting scores for (b)lack and (w)hite
    private static int rScore = 0;
    private static int bScore = 0;

    private static Boolean illegalMove = false;
    private static Boolean redMove;

    public Game() {
        initializeGame();
        gameRunning = true;
    }

    public Boolean gameStarted() {
        return Game.gameRunning;
    }

    // Method to initialize board **COMPLETE**
    public static void initializeGame() {
        for (Piece[] gB1 : gB) {
            for (int col = 0; col < gB1.length; col++) {
                switch (col) {
                    case 1:
                        gB1[col] = new Red(true, false);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        gB1[col] = new Blue(false, true);
                        break;
                    default:
                        gB1[col] = null;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Pick first player randomly
        Random rand = new Random();
        redMove = rand.nextBoolean();
    }

    // Method to print the board **COMPLETE**
    public void printBoard() {
        // Label rows A-H
        char rowLbls = 'A';

        // Label columns 1-8
        System.out.println("   " + Color.BG_PURPLE + " |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  | " + Color.RESET);

        // Print the GameBoard
        for (Piece[] gB1 : gB) {
            System.out.println(
                    Color.BG_PURPLE + "---" + Color.RESET + Color.PURPLE + "---------------------------------------------------" + Color.RESET);
            System.out.print(
                    Color.BG_PURPLE + " " + rowLbls++ + " " + Color.PURPLE + " | " + Color.RESET);
            for (Piece gB11 : gB1) {
                if (gB11 != null) {
                    gB11.placePiece();
                    System.out.print(Color.PURPLE + " | " + Color.RESET);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(Color.PURPLE + "    | " + Color.RESET);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(Color.BG_PURPLE + "¨¨¨" + Color.RESET + Color.PURPLE + "ˋ*-._.-*-._.-*-._.-*-._.-*-._.-*-._.-*-._.-*-._.-* " + Color.RESET);
        System.out.println();
        if (redMove == true) {
            System.out.println(Color.RED + "★·.¸¸.•´¯`•¸¸.•..>> Red's   Move! <<..•.¸¸•´¯`•.¸¸.·★" + Color.RESET);
        } else {
            System.out.println(Color.BLUE + "★·.¸¸.•´¯`•¸¸.•..>> Blue's  Move! <<..•.¸¸•´¯`•.¸¸.·★" + Color.RESET);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Method to test legal moves **IN PROGRESS**
    private boolean legalMove() {

        // Cannot move outside of the board
        if (sRow < 0 || sRow > 8 || sCol < 0 || sCol > 8 || dRow < 0
                || dRow > 8 || dCol < 0 || dCol > 8) {
            System.out.println("You cannot move your piece off of the board");
            return false;
        }

        // You must move from a space that contains your piece
        if (gB[sRow][sCol] == null) {
            System.out.println("There is no piece to move from this space");
            return false;
        }

        // Cannot move another player's piece
        if ((gB[sRow][sCol].rPiece && !redMove)
                || (!gB[sRow][sCol].rPiece && redMove)) {
            if (Game.redMove == true) {
                System.out.println("It is not Blue's turn to move");
            } else if (!(Game.redMove)) {
                System.out.print("It's not Red's turn to move");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Allow multidirectional movement when touching an opponents cell
        if ((gB[dRow][dCol].bPiece && redMove && (sCol == (dCol - 1))) || (gB[dRow][dCol].bPiece && redMove && (sCol == dCol) && (Math.abs(sRow - dRow) == 1))) {
            System.out.print("Red has attacked Blue and gained a point!\n");
            bScore--;
            rScore++;
            return true;
        }

        // Allow multidirectional movement when touching an opponents cell
        if ((gB[dRow][dCol].rPiece && !redMove && (sCol == (dCol + 1))) || (gB[dRow][dCol].bPiece && redMove && (sCol == dCol) && (Math.abs(sRow - dRow) == 1))) {
            System.out.print("Blue has attacked Red and gained a point!\n");
            rScore--;
            bScore++;
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Instructions unclear: Is friendly fire allowed when not popping out
         * of a stock? if ((gB[dRow][sCol].bPiece && !redMove) && ((sCol ==
         * (dCol - 1)) && (Math.abs(sRow - dRow) == 1) || (Math.abs(sRow - dRow)
         * == 1))) { System.out.print("Blue attacked its own! Red gained a
         * point.\n"); bScore--; rScore++; return true; }
         *
         */
        /**
         * Instructions unclear: Is friendly fire allowed when not popping out
         * of a stock? if ((gB[dRow][dCol].rPiece && redMove) && ((sCol == (dCol
         * + 1)) && (Math.abs(sRow - dRow) == 1) || (Math.abs(sRow - dRow) ==
         * 1))) { System.out.print("Red has attacked its own! Blue gained a
         * point.\n"); rScore--; bScore++; return true; }
         *
         */
        // Must only move legal directions otherwise
        if (!gB[sRow][sCol].direction(sRow, sCol, dRow, dCol)) {
            System.out.println("You cannot move in that direction");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void movePiece() {

        System.out.println("    ▁ ▂ ▄ ▅ ▆ ▇ █   Score   █ ▇ ▆ ▅ ▄ ▂ ▁");
        System.out.println("                Red: " + rScore + "          " + bScore + " :Blue");

        if (illegalMove) {
            System.out.print("\nIllegal move.  Please try again: ");
            illegalMove = false;
        } else if (redMove) {
            System.out.print("\nCommand Format: [Row Letter][Column #] to [Row Letter][Column #]\nExample Command: A2 to A3\nText Commands: 'score', 'lostpieces', 'moves'\nRed's move: ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("\nCommand Format: [Row Letter][Column #] to [Row Letter][Column #] \nExample Command: A2 to A3\nText Commands: 'score', 'lostpieces', 'moves'\nBlue's move: ");
        }

        move = input.nextLine();

        if (move.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            gameRunning = false;
            System.out.println("You've ended your game.");
            System.out.println("Red's score: " + rScore + "\nBlue's score: " + bScore);
        }

        String lower = move.toLowerCase();
        String[] userMove = lower.split(" ");

        sCol = (userMove[0].charAt(1) - '1');
        sRow = (userMove[0].charAt(0) - 'a');
        dCol = (userMove[2].charAt(1) - '1');
        dRow = (userMove[2].charAt(0) - 'a');

        if (legalMove()) {
            updateScore();
            gB[dRow][dCol] = gB[sRow][sCol];
            gB[sRow][sCol] = null;
            redMove = !redMove;
        } else {
            illegalMove = true;
            printBoard();
            movePiece();
        }
    }

    private void updateScore() {
        if (gB[dRow][dCol] == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (redMove) {
            rScore += gB[dRow][dCol].value();
            lostPieces.push("B");
        } else {
            bScore += gB[dRow][dCol].value();
            lostPieces.push("R");

        }
    }

}
```

The main movement of the piece is listed in each piece class:

```
    // Red movement from Col 2 in Red.java
    @Override
    public boolean direction(int sRow, int sCol, int dRow, int dCol) {
        if (this.rPiece) {
            return ((sRow == dRow) && sCol == (dCol - 1));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Blue movement from Col 7 in Blue.java
    @Override
    public boolean direction(int sRow, int sCol, int dRow, int dCol) {
        if (this.bPiece) {
            return ((sRow == dRow) && sCol == (dCol - 1));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cit230.pkgfinal.Game.legalMove(Game.java:123)
    at cit230.pkgfinal.Game.movePiece(Game.java:196)
    at cit230.pkgfinal.CIT230Final.newGame(CIT230Final.java:55)
    at cit230.pkgfinal.CIT230Final.runMenu(CIT230Final.java:31)
    at cit230.pkgfinal.CIT230Final.main(CIT230Final.java:17)

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.
```

Comment: When you ask about an exception you need to include the full stack trace and error message, and indicate which line in your code it refers to.

Comment: I updated it. Thank you.

Comment: You have an 8 by 8 board, so coordinates need to be 0..7 inclusive, you are checking e.g. `dRow > 8`.

Comment: But also you set the contents of the `gB` array to `null` where there is no piece, so `gB[dRow][dCol].bPiece` will give the NPE. You need to check that `gB[dRow][dCol]` isn't `null` first.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Next time you have an error like this, try stepping through with a debugger, or setting a breakpoint at the line where you are getting the exception.